# Explain this case please

Tags: grammar, meaning, grammaticality-in-context

Yesterday I had to answer to this seller question: -Will you come back?

I thought that I could answer like that:

I will come much more times here.

I will come here more often.

How to answer correctly to the question? Are these answers both incorrect?

Thank you for your reply!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will come much more times here.

This is incorrect. In this case "many" such be used instead of "much". However even then it seems unnatural. It may be my personal word choice, however I would say:

> I plan to visit frequently.

or

> I hope to visit often.

The second one:

> I will come here often.

This is technically fine, but it seems unnatural. I think "to come" is perhaps too generic.

You may also want to consider the word frequently, it is heard more commonly in situations with stores.